# After SSH authentication failures (Centos 7) something blocked my IP

Tags: ssh, firewall, openssh, sshd

A newer server admin tried to set me up to authenticate SSH using a public key. It wasn't configured correctly, and SSH kept asking me for password (and he kept telling me to hit enter).  Unexpectedly, I am no longer able to connect to the server at all on any port.  (It is a public web server.)

I spoke to the more senior Sysadmin and he couldn't figure out what happened.  It feels very much like some service similar to [fail2ban](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-fail2ban-on-centos-7) blocked the ip, but the sysadmin is sure it isn't on the server.  (I also double checked `systemctl` and `etc`, and I don't see it.)

Also there is no rule in iptables blocking my IP.

Where are other places to look for something blocking the IP?  (I've also checked /var/log but don't see any obvious log files that show the block.)

Note: the server is in a Digital Ocean data center.  I ran tracert, and the last IP it reported before timing out was 138.197.244.33 (which looks like a Digital Ocean front door).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a lot of detective work and finally checking the list of running services more carefully:

`systemctl list-units --type=service --all | grep running`

I found that `lfd.service (ConfigServer Firewall & Security - lfd)` was running (not being a Linux sysadmin, I didn't know anything about it), and this turned out to be the culprit. The lfd.service does indeed monitor authentication failures and then blacklists IPs in `/etc/csf/csf.deny`.

To remove the IP from the blacklist use:

`csf -dr <the IP>`

Here is [a helpful guide to CSF](https://www.hostdime.com/kb/hd/command-line/useful-csf-ssh-command-line-commands-csf-cheat-sheet).